# Removing buttons from home screen

Tags: android, button, launcher, homescreen

Can anyone point me on how to remove the existing buttons from the Android Launcher. I would like to remove the phone and explorer buttons and keep only the app drawer button. I went through the source code but couldn't notice three buttons being created. I was able to achieve the same with different home replacement app but it would be great if I could do it with default launcher app. Thanks.